# Number of solutions to $a^2-b^2+c^2 = k\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $k\neq 0$ be a fixed integer. How many triplets $(a,b,c)$ are there satisfying $$a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}\equiv k\pmod{p}$$ I know that if $c=0$, then there are $p-1$. Not sure for the general case

Answer (score 3):

Let $N_k$ be the number of solutions.

Define the Gauss sum $\tau=\sum_{a=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{a^2}$ where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/p)$.
Then
$$\tau^2\overline{\tau}=\sum_{a,b,c=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{a^2-b^2+c^2}
=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} N_k\zeta^k.$$
 So
$$p\tau=p\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\left(\frac kp\right)\zeta^k=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} N_k\zeta^k=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(N_k-N_0)\zeta^k.$$
Here  $\left(\frac kp\right)$ is the Legendre symbol. Since $\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{p-1}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, then
it follows that $N_k-N_0=p\left(\frac kp\right)$. So
$$N_k=N_0+p\left(\frac kp\right).$$
Adding over all $k$ gives
$$p^3=pN_0$$
so
$$N_k=p^2+p\left(\frac kp\right).$$

Comment: Emm. You have a great name :) BTW, can't this be done without using Gauss sums??

Comment: @S.C. but Gauss sums are great fun!

Comment: They are but i am not used to them as of now. There is too much machinery being used here.

Comment: Why does $p\tau = \tau^2 \bar{\tau}$?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut $|\tau|^2=p$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this result; is it relatively elementary?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut It's fairly straightforward

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So how do i count the number of solutions to $a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}=1\pmod{p}$. Is it just $p^{3}+p^{2}$??

Comment: @S.C. Using the method in my answer you get $p^3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Emm. Could you please elaborate on that. I mean to find the solution i think it's enough if we know what $\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}p^{2}+p\left(\frac{1+i^2}{p}\right)$ counts. It turns out to be $p^3-p$

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem if $c\neq 0$?

Fix $c$, then $c^2$ leaves some remainder when divided by $p$, now if you move $c^2$ to the left-hand side of the equation, and let $k-c^2$**(mod p)**=$k$', so we have to find the number of solutions

$a^2+b^2=k'$ **(mod p)**

As you said if $k'\neq 0$ then it has $p-1$ solutions, so if $k$ is not a square modulo $p$(i.e $k'$ is not zero for any value of $c$) then the number of solutions of the original equation is $(p-1) \times p$.

Note that $a^2+b^2=0$ **(mod p)**  has $p+(p-1)=2p-1$ solutions.

Now say $k'=0$ for some $c\neq 0$ (i.e. $k$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ and $k\neq 0$), then for exactly $2$ values of $c$, $k'=0$ and the equation will have $2p-1$ solutions for those $2$ values and for the rest $p-2$ values of $c$ we will have $p-1$ pairs of $(a,b)$ for each value of $c$, hence the total number of solutions of the original congruence in this case is $(p-2)\times (p-1)+2(2p-1)=p^2+p$, when $k\neq 0$ is a quadradic residue modulo $p$.

If $k=0$, then for $c=0$ the congruence has exactly $2p-1$ solutions and for all other $p-1$ values of $c$ the congruence has $p-1$ solutions for each $c$.
Hence, in this case, the total number of solution is $(p-1)^2+2p-1=p^2$

Comment: I got $p^2+p$ solutions when $k$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: take $p=3$ , $k=1$, i think i'm getting $9$ solutions, pls check, either your or my answer is wrong

Comment: (0,0,1), (1,1,1), (2,2,1), (1,2,1), (2,1,1), (1,2,2), (2,1,2), (1,1,2), (2,2,2), (0,0,2), (1,0,0), (2,0,0)

Comment: now both of our solutions are correct

Comment: what is your real name? where do you study?